# Waviness/ridges in skim coat

Tags: drywall

I’m having an issue with my skim coating. I’m using a paint roller and squeegee with the plus3 joint compound.  I had textured walls that were painted.  I have applied multiple layers of joint compound but I’m still getting this wavy look to my walls, almost like cellulite. It’s also happening on my ceilings. I am attaching a few pictures. I’m not sure what to do.  Is the mud too thin? Do I need to sand more in between applications.? Should I have used a quick bond/easy sand mud instead of +3? Thank you for your input.[image]

Comment: What do you really mean by squeegee? Conventional drywallers skim with a wide (~14”) metal blade drywall knife. How big is your sanding pad? (Can recommend the 9” round, ie Radius360 brand, over any small rectangular one.)

Comment: And at this point, you’d be better off using a real topping compound — it’s vastly easier to sand.